# Check for perfect number and print out divisors?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to create a program that checks whether the user input is a perfect number or not. It has validation for the numbers entered. If the input IS a perfect number, I'd like to print out each of the divisors. I tried using this method:

```
 {
for(int number=2; number <= 10000 ; number++)
    perfect(number);
return 0;
}
void perfect(int number)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++)
{
        if (number % i == 0)
    total += i;         
} 
    if (number == total)
{
    for (int x = 1; x < number; x++)
    {
        if (number % x == 0)
            cout << x << " + ";
    }
    cout << " = " << number << endl;
}
}
```

However, I was unable to get the desired effect. I am very new to javascript and am struggling with inserting code in the correct way. Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can get the desired effect? Here is the code I have already written:

```
function check_prime() {
var input = document.getElementById("enteredNumber").value;
var number = parseInt(input);

if (isNaN(number)) {
alert("Oops! Please enter a valid number.");
document.getElementById("enteredNumber").value="";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  "";
document.getElementById("enteredNumber").focus();

        }

else if (input.length === 0) {
alert("Please enter a number.");
document.getElementById("enteredNumber").focus();

        }

else if (!isNaN(number)) {
            if (is_perfect(number)) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =     "Congratulations! " + number + " is a perfect number." ;
                        }

            else {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "I'm sorry. " + number + " is not a perfect number. Try Again.";
                        }
                    }
            else {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Please enter a number.";
                    }
                }


function is_perfect(number)  
{  
var temp = 0;  
for(var i=1;i<=number/2;i++)  
    {  
    if(number%i === 0)  
        {  
            temp += i;  
              }  
        }  

    if(temp === number)  
        {  
            return true;  
              }   
         else  
            {  
           return false;
              }     
     }   

function clear_textbox(){
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =  "";
document.getElementById("enteredNumber").value="";
document.getElementById("enteredNumber").focus();

    }
```

Comment: What is the desired effect you are not achieving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest revising your `is_perfect()` function to return an array of divisors if the number is perfect and `null` if the number is not perfect. Then the calling code has the divisors available for display when the input is a perfect number.

```
function is_perfect(number) {
    var temp = 0;
    var divisors = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=number/2;i++) {
        if (number%i === 0) {
            divisors.push(i);
            temp += i;
        }
    }  

    return temp === number ? divisors : null;
 }
```

Then:

```
var divisors = is_perfect(number);
if (divisors) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =     "Congratulations! " + number + " is a perfect number.";
    // display the divisors somewhere; the alert is just for show
    alert("Divisors: " + divisors.toString());
} else {
    ...
}
```

[Note: In an earlier version of this answer, I had initialized `temp` to 1 and `divisors` to `[1]` and had started the loop at 2, on the theory that 1 is always a divisor. Unfortunately, that's wrong, since 1 is not a *proper* divisor of 1. The revised version of `is_perfect()` now returns `null` for an argument of 1 instead of `[1]`. An alternative fix would have been to test explicitly for the case `number === 1`, but that's uglier (if perhaps a tiny bit more efficient, since it avoids one `%` evaluation).]

Answer (score 0):

so I use `2^(n-1)*(2^n -1)` formula (to generate a perfect number) and checking if last digit is 6 or 8 to check if `x` is perfect number.

Note: It's not perfect 100%

```js
function pn(x) {
    x = '' + x
    for (var i = 0; i < Infinity; i++) {
        perfnumgen = Math.pow(2, i - 1) * (Math.pow(2, i) - 1)
        if (x === "" + perfnumgen && (perfnumgen % 10 === 8 || perfnumgen % 10 === 6))
            return true
        else if (perfnumgen > x)
            return false
        console.log("" + perfnumgen)
    }
}
```